# "All boot options are tried" after running wrong command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot

I had a Windows/Ubuntu dual boot working just fine, but after messing around with some stuff, I ended up breaking my Windows boot. Searching through the internet, I found some [neat commands](https://ubunlog.com/en/how-to-fix-windows-mbr-from-ubuntu/#Syslinux) that I thought would fix my problem, here I reproduce them:

```
> sudo apt-get install syslinux
> sudo dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr.bin of=/dev/sda2
```

My Ubuntu is in `/dev/sda1`, so I thought I was pretty sure about what I was doing. I ran the commands, restarted my PC and, surprise, got the "All boot options are tried, press F4 key..." screen. I then booted a Ubuntu USB recovery to run the Boot Repair tool, which executed just fine, but I still got the same screen. I went back to my live USB system and checked the partitions, apparently the NTFS partition got corrupted, so I thought that was the problem. I deleted all the Windows partitions (they weren't that important), ran the Boot Repair tool again, but still, I get the same screen.

In my BIOS menu, fast boot and secure boot are disabled, "CSM and UEFI" option is selected, but no device shows up in the boot priority. What am I missing here? How can I recover my Ubuntu boot?

EDIT: Additionally, on the first time I ran Boot Repair, I noted down the pastebin logs: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/DpsHZ27sK6/ -- not sure if this offers any useful information.

Comment: Can you restore a previous disk image? The NTFS partition is already damaged.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik unfortunately, not. I checked my /dev/sda1 and all my linux files are untouched. I deleted the NTFS partitions, so they are not the problem. I guess the only thing left is to make Ubuntu boot again, but I keep getting that "All boot options are tried" screen. That means the HD has no bootable partitions, right? But I've set the bios_grub flag in the grub partition and it doesn't get detected.